# How to edit multiple values in database in one time

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, http

I am making an admin panel for my website.
I have problem editing many values in a database at one time.
My website is https://jaguarz.cf but the admin panel is not visible to common visitors and only i can control it

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

I get this error while counting no of id s i want to change

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_features'])) {

    $count=count($_POST['id_edit']);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
            $sql1="UPDATE projects 
                    SET name='" . $_POST['name_edit'][$i] . "', 
                        link='" . $_POST['link_edit'][$i] . "', 
                        rank='" . $_POST['rank_edit'][$i] . "' 
                WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'][$i] . "'";
            $result1=mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my form:

```
<form method="post" action="admin_panel" style="margin:auto;" class="resize form-style-8">
  <div class="table-responsive" style="width:99%;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Id</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Name</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Link</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Rank</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="id_edit" value="1" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name_edit" value="Videos"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="link_edit" value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXqIrdlG-gsfSGuFUt0v-1g"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rank_edit" value="AAA"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="id_edit" value="2" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name_edit" value="Basic Message Encrypter And Decrypter"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="link_edit" value="project?page=en-decrypter"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rank_edit" value="B"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="id_edit" value="5" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name_edit" value="Calculator"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="link_edit" value="project?page=calculator"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rank_edit" value="E"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px">
      <button type="submit" name="edit_features" class="btn btn-info text-justify" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; width:auto; text-align:center !important;">Edit Projects</button>
    </div>
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="table-responsive" style="width:99%;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Id</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Name</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Link</th>
          <th style="color: rgb(0,0,0);font-size: 20px;">Rank</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Auto Generated</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name_add"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="link_add"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rank_add"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px">
      <button type="submit" name="add_features" class="btn btn-danger text-justify" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; width:auto; text-align:center !important;">Add Projects</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I expect it to change all values at one time

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197979/discussion-on-question-by-legendary-jaguarz-how-to-edit-multiple-values-in-datab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of principal issues with your code:

```
<input type="text" name="id_edit" value="1" disabled>
```

(as per your original code)

In these inputs

1) `disabled` elements do not get submitted by the browser. You should change them to `readonly` (as you've already done in your edit)

2) `name="id_edit"` is repeated multiple times, but you can't have multiple items with the same name - the server will only see one of them. To make it submit an array of values under the same name, change it to `name="id_edit[]"`. You need to do this for all your repeatable fields.

The last issue is a typo in your server code:

```
WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'][$i] . "'";
```

needs to be

```
WHERE id='" . $_POST['id_edit'][$i] . "'";
```

because you aren't submitting any field called `id` in your form.

---

Lastly I'm going to issue a broader warning, for an issue you need to rectify now you've got the form working on a basic level: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Thanks you are great
it helped me

Answer (score 0):

you got that warning message because you pass a single value data inside form you need to modified attribute name in each tag input like this

```
<tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="id_edit[]" value="1" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_edit[]" value="Videos"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="link_edit[]" value="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXqIrdlG-gsfSGuFUt0v-1g"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rank_edit[]" value="AAA"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="id_edit[]" value="2" readonly></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name_edit[]" value="Basic Message Encrypter And Decrypter"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="link_edit[]" value="project?page=en-decrypter"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rank_edit[]" value="B"></td>
    </tr>
```

as above you send an array to php that you can use count for every data has sent from the form and do your stuff on php as well.

but I tell you that way is not the best way.. maybe you can use

> data[]['id_edit']

in name attribute as well so you just need to

> count($_POST['data'])

without worrying about imbalance count for every data

Comment: Already chated a lot with @ADyson and did that . But Thanks !